# Close nested UI Bootstrap accordion when parent closes

Tags: angularjs, accordion, directive, transclusion

In AngularJS I am using a bootstrapUI accordion directive that contains a nested accordion in one of the panes.

When I close the 'parent' I would like to close its 'children'. I am having trouble because the accordion directive uses transclusion, and the scopes are actually siblings not parent to child.

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl"> 
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Nested Accordian">
        <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
          <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
            This content is straight in the template.
          </accordion-group>
          <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            {{group.content}}
          </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

**[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1vDhTG?p=preview)**

Comment: I took the bootstrapUI source and extended it to keep track of inheritance in rootScope by 'id' element attribute. This does not feel like the 'angular way' so I am still interested in another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing close-others= true;