# How to close nested ui-bootstrap accordion when parent closes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The Problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753595/close-nested-ui-bootstrap-accordion-when-parent-closes)(**I need to close inner accordion automatically, when I close outer/Parent Accordion**)  is not answered till now. Can anyone help me to get the solution for the above stated problem please. ..Thank you so much in advance...

"*Click here to see the [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1vDhTG?p=preview)*"

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl"> 
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Nested Accordian">
        <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
          <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
            This content is straight in the template.
          </accordion-group>
          <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            {{group.content}}
          </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add an accordion-heading on the parent instead of the heading attribute so we can add on-click event like this :

```
 <accordion-group >
        <accordion-heading>
          <span  ng-click='onParentCollapse()'>Nested Accordian</span>
        </accordion-heading>
```

instead of the old one :

```
 <accordion-group  heading="Nested Accordian">
```

then define an object to handle the status of the static child accordions :

```
  $scope.staticAccordionsFlag = {
    open : false
  };
```

then alter the groups to have an extra attribute for the dynamic childs :

```
  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
      content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1",
      open: false
    },
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
      content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2",
      open: false
    }
  ];
```

then define the function `onParentCollapse` : in the controller

```
  $scope.onParentCollapse = function(){

   //for the ones dynamicly generated 
   angular.forEach($scope.groups, function(element) {
      element.open = false;
    });

    //for the static ones
    $scope.staticAccordionsFlag.open = false;

  }
```

finally adjust the child accordions to have the linked dynamic flags to be open or nor :

```
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
          <accordion-group is-open="staticAccordionsFlag.open" heading="Static Header">
            This content is straight in the template.
          </accordion-group>
          <accordion-group is-open="group.open" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            {{group.content}}
          </accordion-group>
```

if you got lost here is your full code : 
HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl"> 
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group>
        <accordion-heading>
          <span  ng-click='onParentCollapse()'>Nested Accordian</span>
        </accordion-heading>
        <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
          <accordion-group is-open="staticAccordionsFlag.open" heading="Static Header">
            This content is straight in the template.
          </accordion-group>
          <accordion-group is-open="group.open" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
            {{group.content}}
          </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

and the JS :

```
function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
      content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1",
      open: false
    },
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
      content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2",
      open: false
    }
  ];



  $scope.staticAccordionsFlag = {
    open : false
  };

  $scope.onParentCollapse = function(){

   //for the ones dynamicly generated 
   angular.forEach($scope.groups, function(element) {
      element.open = false;
    });

    //for the static ones
    $scope.staticAccordionsFlag.open = false;

  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, But for the latest plugin     <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script> and **without including**     _<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">_ , I need to work...But it is not working for these conditions(since, i need to include these conditions for the project containing latest version of ui-bootstrap and without twitter bootstrap which was already done)      [plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dkIJl7D3szu1rhWoFwBE?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, **I got Answer for above question, Thank you**....[New Plunker is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/95WfamNB485g6BsjNSzo?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by keeping track of the selected group.
In this example I've added a custom html tag called handler (you could add an other, I've just made it up) to wrap the accordion-groups and make sure the handler tags ng-click fire before the directive click event.

First, add these to the scope

```
$scope.m = {};
  $scope.m.isSelected = '';
  $scope.m.set = function(value){
    $scope.m.isSelected = value; 
  };
```

Then call the m.set when each handler is clicked

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl"> 
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group close-others="false">
      <accordion-heading><span ng-click="m.set('none')">Nested Accordian</span></accordion-heading>
        <accordion>
          <handler ng-click="m.set('Static')">
          <accordion-group is-open="m.isSelected == 'Static'">
            <accordion-heading><span >Static Header</span></accordion-heading>
            This content is straight in the template.
          </accordion-group>
          </handler>
          <handler ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-click="m.set(group.title)">
          <accordion-group is-open="m.isSelected == group.title">
           <accordion-heading><span>{{group.title}}</span></accordion-heading>
            {{group.content}}
          </accordion-group>
          </handler>
        </accordion>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/52seKq?p=preview)

Comment: @ShaileshBhat np! upvote/accept answer if help was provided

Comment: Sorry, But for the latest plugin     <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script> and **without including**     _<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">_ , I need to work...But it is not working for these conditions(since, i need to include these conditions for the project containing latest version of ui-bootstrap and without twitter bootstrap which was already done)      [plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yVuhtY3gkzkcsY7WZzqY?p=preview) @Marcus-H

Comment: Yes, **I got Answer for above question, Thank you**....[New Plunker is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/95WfamNB485g6BsjNSzo?p=preview)